# how to do angular update current user value of username in local storage

Tags: html, css, angular6, typescript2.0

[image: how to update localstorage of a currentsUser for only username when i update username its not reflecting in localstorage,am able to see the change in component page]

[image: in console application localstorage null is stored key and value is {username:gasd} it's not joining in that json. of currentUser]

> how to update local storage of a current User for only username when i update username its not reflecting in localstorage,am able to see the change in component page in console am getting null value for  item and in console application localstorage null is stored key and value is {username:gasd} its not joining in that json. by using angular6

```
  let item =localStorage.getItem(this.currentUser);
  console.log(item);
  let myobj = {username:changeValue};
  localStorage.setItem(item, JSON.stringify(myobj));
```

Answer (score 0):

Think of localStorage as a key-value dictionary.
You use **string** keys to get/set **string** values. (more on that in [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage))
So for objects you can do for example:

```js
let myObj = {};
my["myKey"] = "myVal"; // note that in objects, values don't need to be strings
my["myKey2"] = 2;
my["myKey3"] = {};
```

In localStorage however it's strings on both sides:

```js
localStorage.setItem("currentUser", {username: "ganes"}); // BAD
localStorage.setItem({username: "ganes"}, "someValue"); // BAD
localStorage.getItem({username: "ganes"}) // BAD

let currentUserDataStr = localStorage.getItem("currentUser"); // GOOD
// something along these lines
let currentUserData = JSON.parse(currentUserDataStr);
// do some mutation on currentUserData
currentUserData.currentUser = "ganesNew"
let newUserDataStr = JSON.stringify(currentUserData)
localStorage.setItem("currentUser", newUserDataStr); // GOOD
```

Comment: getting null value for currentUserDataStr

Comment: if you open up DevTools and go to Application (like in the screenshot in your question) do you see any entries under 'currentUser'?

Comment: i saw  it in application but this code not worked for me i have written in different it worked thnks